# How to dump flash memory with SPI?

Tags: hardware, spi

Often flash memory is connected via SPI (Serial Peripheral Interface Bus) to a processing unit like an ARM core or a micro controller.

- How can one dump the memory?
- Can there be protection mechanisms?
- Are there pitfalls to avoid?

Comment: This question is too general. Acessing an SPI flash is practically trivial. And if you want any more specifics you should be refering to the datasheet of your device rather than stackexchange. If you had a question about a specific device.... that might be easier to answer.

Comment: It may be trivial for you, but it may be not trivial for others. For some people it is the first time they do this and they are seeking for guidance. Why not have some general tips on this RE Q&A site? Dumping flash memory is a common task in reversing hardware. So ew coukd point at the BusPirate or Arduino code to do it. My question is an attempt to get `hardware` more exposure.

Comment: Then they should ask on the EE stackexchange. There is no reason to ask a question about something that is most likely plainly documented on RE. If someone does ask a question about a specific device then they will be welcome to do so otherwise the quesiton turns into a list of datasheets essentially!

Comment: EE people often have labs with special hardware and know exactly which chips they're dealing with. In short, they don't necessarily operate in similar conditions. An answer from RE viewpoint will be useful.

Comment: I think this is a relatively good question - there are a number of points that can be raised like in-situ reading or removed, reading out entire contents vs sniffing in use.

Comment: I used to use a programmer to read and write flash before, after desoldering it from the board.

Comment: When trying to dump the memory while keeping the device in-circuit. it may be helpful to force the processor to reset (keep pushing the reset button or setting the reset pin to gnd) thus the host processor releash chip select pin and another tool can communicate with it.

Comment: I have a question about buspirate_spi programmer and flashrom. I have a new Flash rom Boye BY25Q128AS similar to the winbond W25Q128.V in the flashrom list. How can I dump the data from this specific IC that not available in flashrom?

Answer (score 24):

Although I think the questions are too broad and I agree with @cb88 that the datasheet should give you all you need to know, I'll try to answer some.

## How to dump the memory

1. ### Desoldering

   First option is desoldering the chip from the board. After having done so you have 2 options

   - Read the chip out using a chip programmer like e.g. [Dataman](http://www.dataman.com/) that supports your chip ($$$ expensive solution).
   - Or use a cheap micro controller based solution like a [Bus Pirate](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate), an [Ardunio](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI) or code your own dumper (which is generally not too hard).
2. ### In Circuit

   When you can't or don't want to remove the chip you have again 2 options.

   - First one is again using a professional programmer or the cheap micro controller based ones mentioned above. There are definitely some pitfalls with this method which I'll describe when answering your 3rd question
   - Alternatively you can monitor the SPI lines and use a Logic Analyzer or micro controller to decode the signals. The downside is that you don't control the addresses that are being read and so you have to somehow generate activity to the SPI Flash and then reconstruct the flash image based on the addresses that are being accessed.

You can also use a [clip](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13153) that is designed to attach the analyzer to the chip in-system.

In general I'd really recommend to desolder the chip. They're almost, if not always edge packaged (e.g. having clearly visible pins on the outside of the package) and not [Ball Grid Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) (BGA) packages. This makes them easy to remove and also easy to put back. It will save you the headaches you might encounter that I described in the pitfalls section below.

## Protection mechanisms

- **OTP memory** Some of these chips can include One-Time Programmable (OTP) memory in which they store protection bits. I've only seen this being used for locking down area's against writing, not against reading. Otherwise what's the point of having the flash memory?
- **Encryption** I have never seen nor could I quickly find any SPI flash chips that offer encryption. This is usually implemented in a memory controller on the System on a Chip (SoC) side that does it on the fly keeping it nice and transparent for the host CPU.

## Pitfalls to avoid

Some things to keep in mind;

- I have nearly no good experiences while trying to dump the memory while keeping the device in-circuit. There are allot of reasons why this could go wrong.

  1. The host processors keeps the SPI Flash busy while running it's own program
  2. A watch-dog on the host side resets the board because it's peripheral became inaccessible for too long due to you accessing it
  3. When you choose to provide the power to the chip yourself, then your programmer/reader might not be able to supply enough current if there's multiple components on the same power rail
- In case you're writing your own sniffer make sure it can sample the signals fast enough. For example the bus pirate will fail in all cases because it can only sample at max ~32MHz where allot of SPI Flashes start at 40+MHz. So you'll need at least double the target speed ([Sampling Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem))

  The flash devices can work at various speeds up to 100+MHz which relate to the various modes (normal read, fast read, dual read, quad read etc) they're in. Such a mode does not only change the speed, but also the way data is transferred. For example in Quad Read mode the flash clocks out 4 bits bits at a time using the SI/SO/WP/Hold signals instead of 'classic' mode where you read out 1 bit per clock cycle from SO (Serial Out).
- When acting as the host just make sure you provide enough power and that the signals are high/low at the right times. All this information can be found in the datasheet of the flash chips.

Comment: I would first see if I couldn't just hold the processor in reset and then just scan out the spi port. No point in desoldering a whole chip when you can force it into high-z. The other note would be see if there are any zero ohm/100ohm inline resistors on the clk/ SDI/SDO pins and remove those if so and replace with your probe. But good comments... just some additional things to think about.